# Unable to charge my device

Tags: usb, charging

I connected my device to the laptop through the U.S.B cable and tried to charge but it's not charging the device.Although it is connecting the device normally for data transfer but it's not charging the device as it used to.

The device is not getting charged even through the Wall socket provided by the Manufacturer.Now what can i do to get it charged back to normal.

Device:Samsung Galaxy trend(GT-S7392)

Android:4.1.2 Jelly bean

Comment: Sounds more like a hardware problem/failure! Check all the hardware devices again.

Answer (score 2):

I simply turned OFF the device, disconnected the battery from the mains and waited for 2-5 minutes (placed the battery separate from the device).

Later cleaned the terminals with a soft cloth ,placed the battery inside and connected the socket .

Started charging the device i power off mode itself for some time and later when i switched on the device it was successfully charging the device.

Lucky it was removable battery.(else had to go for a genuine service center and deposit the device for some time )